# Matlab GUI: Problems while using imfreehand()

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have applied Canny edge detection on am image and now want to crop a part of it for further procession. I have created 4 axes with the tags axes1, axes2, axes3 and axes4. I want to display the image first in axes1, then the edge detected again in axes1. Finally the cropped image is to be displayed in axes3 and the image after removal of holes in axes4.

I am including a sample code which recreates the problem:

```
function varargout = samp_GUI(varargin)

 % Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
 gui_Singleton = 1;
 gui_State = struct('gui_Name', mfilename, 'gui_Singleton',         gui_Singleton, 'gui_OpeningFcn', @samp_GUI_OpeningFcn, 'gui_OutputFcn',  @samp_GUI_OutputFcn, 'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , 'gui_Callback',   []);
 if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
  gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
 end

 if nargout
  [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
 else
  gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
 end
 % End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before samp_GUI is made visible.
function samp_GUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
 handles.output = hObject;
 guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = samp_GUI_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
 varargout{1} = handles.output;

% --- Executes on button press in browse.
function browse_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 [filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.bmp'},'File Selector');
 handles.myImage = strcat(pathname, filename);
 axes(handles.axes1);
 imshow(handles.myImage)
 im=imread(handles.myImage);

 bw3=im2bw(im,0.3); %threshold value taken as 0.3
 BW3=edge(bw3,'canny');
 edge_im = BW3;
 axes(handles.axes1);
 imshow(BW3);

 h=imfreehand(handles.axes1);
 M=~h.createMask();
 I(M) = 0;

 axes(handles.axes2);
 imshow(I);title('Cropped Image')
 I = bwareaopen(I, 50);
 axes(handles.axes3);
 imshow(I),title('Removed Holes');
 % save the updated handles object
 guidata(hObject,handles);
```

When i execute the code in a .m file, it runs perfectly with different images opening in different windows but when the same code is run for the GUI, blank images are problems. I do not seem understand where the problem lies.

Comment: I recommend using `subplot` instead, way easier.

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow generally should contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code that you have posted is not complete nor verifiable. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34708069/edit) your question to ensure that the code in your question is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more).

Comment: I tried `subplot` too but the same error persisted. It seems as if `imfreehand()` is not taking any input despite me marking an ROI on the image.

Comment: @flawr I'm not sure how `subplot` is going to be easier, if he can't address the existing axes I'm not sure how addressing the return of `subplot` (more axes object handles) is going to be any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're suffering from some form of copy/paste issue. If you look at the line in your code where `I(M) = 0` this doesn't really make sense (given your example) since I is not defined.

MATLAB will not throw any errors at this point though, because it's perfectly valid to create a matrix in this way; however, doing so actually produces a row vector rather than the image you're wanting.

```
>> M = logical(eye(100));
>> size(M)

ans =

   100   100

>> clear I
>> I(M) = 0;
>> size(I)

ans =

           1       10000
```

I imagine what you wanted to do was to apply the mask to your image (`im`) in which case you should get what you want. I have provided an example below (not sure what you're trying to display in axes1).

```
load mri
img = double(D(:,:,12));
im = img ./ max(img(:));

figure

handles.axes1 = subplot(2,2,1);
handles.axes2 = subplot(2,2,2);
handles.axes3 = subplot(2,2,3);
handles.axes4 = subplot(2,2,4);

bw3=im2bw(im,0.3); %threshold value taken as 0.3
BW3=edge(bw3,'canny');
edge_im = BW3;
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(BW3);

h=imfreehand(handles.axes1);
M=~h.createMask();

% Assign im to I to ensure proper cropping.
I = im;
I(M) = 0;

axes(handles.axes3);
imshow(I);title('Cropped Image')
M_noholes = bwareaopen(M, 50);
I(M_noholes) = 0;
axes(handles.axes4);
imshow(I),title('Removed Holes');
```

If you provide more information it will be easier to help you figure out what you need.